# How to apply Grayscale to the image and add text

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

Can anyone help me out, I want the image to turn to grayscale and add some text and make half of the image transparent . below are the images, want to do exactly the same
[image: colored image]

[image: grayscale image with text and transparent color]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a grayscale filter using CSS.

```
#yourImgID {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

Comment: The other parts of the question I do not quite understand your desired result... Like the bottom image?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you want, but to give your image an overlay after using a grayscale filter on it, you can do something like this in CSS:

```
#myImage::before { content: url(images/overlay-image.png); }
```

That would add the overlay image on top of your existing image; you may have to play with "position" for fine tuning, e.g.:

```
#myImage { position: relative; }

#myImage::before { 
content: url(images/overlay-image.png);
position: absolute; 
top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; }
```

EDIT:

You can also wrap a div around your images and do the following:

CSS

```
.img-con {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 4px dotted #000;
    background-color: #DDD;
}
.img-con img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.img-con img:first-of-type {
    -webkit-filter: opacity(50%);
    /* opacity: 0.5; */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.img-con img:last-of-type {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="img-con">
<img src="#" alt="#" width="300" height="444" />
<img src="#" alt="#" width="300" height="444" />
</div>
```

Take a look

```css
 .img-con {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   border: 4px dotted #000;
   background-color: #DDD;
 }
 .img-con img {
   vertical-align: top;
 }
 .img-con img:first-of-type {
   -webkit-filter: opacity(50%);
   /* opacity: 0.5; */
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
 }
 .img-con img:last-of-type {
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
 }
```

```html
<div class="img-con">
  <img src="http://www.mafab.hu/static/2014/265/14/2259_15.jpg" alt="#" width="300" height="444" />
  <img src="https://az620379.vo.msecnd.net/images/Contracts/small_894f7d50-8ea0-4d93-b114-75d4e79404a2.jpg" alt="#" width="300" height="444" />
</div>
```